# Download jars from repo using curl in loop

Tags: bash, shell

```
Cat files.env
Dblfile1-api
Dblffile2
Dbmfile3-api
Dbmfile4-
```

hi I want to read a files.env get lines (filenames) matching a pattern as variable and download the files and save it in loop . tried the below.

```
grep -i dbl files.env  |
    while IFS= read -r -d '' x ;do
       curl -X -L GET https://myownrepo/"$x"/ver/"$x".jar --output "$x"
    done
```

any advice to achieve this.

Ideally I want to grep all lines that has Dbl , --> Dblfile1-api,Dblfile2-api pass it in while loop and download.my file and save it.

Comment: Please add some additional info, what didn't work? Any errors?

Comment: Perhaps you need to provide more detail? What doesn't work? The downloaded `jar` will be called `x` every time. Could that be the problem? Details please.

Comment: I have edited my query to make more sense . i have a file with list of names . i want to grep all  lines(filenames) that match my  pattern and if it matches  i want curl download it and save them

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where your problems are, but from what you tried to achive, you can do this by using this script - perhaps you missed the shebang or anything else. I removed the line break, to eliminate misinterpretation, but the rest worked fined. Also I put an echo statement after the curl so that you can see what is being polled. FYI - in my example of recreation, I didn't require a delimiter:

```
#!/bin/bash

grep -i dbl files.env  | while IFS= read -r x
do
        curl -X -L GET https://myownrepo/"$x"/ver/"$x".jar --output "$x"
        echo  https://myownrepo/"$x"/ver/"$x".jar
done

exit 0
```

Result:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: GET
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: myownrepo
https://myownrepo/Dblfile1-api/ver/Dblfile1-api.jar
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: GET
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: myownrepo
https://myownrepo/Dblffile2/ver/Dblffile2.jar
```